# Unexpected access to "event" variable across browsers?

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

Let me begin by saying I understand that the below code has a major issue. Specifically, the `event` parameter is not passed into the function. What I don't understand is why in the below code Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox, and IE all treat the `event` variable differently.

```
$('#eventBtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

In Chrome, Opera, and Safari the above code works. IE fails at the second line and Firefox fails immediately. For testing purposes I have created a slightly more embellished [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsteele/MFtnn/). The output of the above `console.log(event)` in the various browsers:

> Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m
>     MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null, toElement: button#superBtn, fromElement: null,
>         y: 20, x: 33…}
>
> Opera Version 12.15
>     MouseEvent
>
> Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)
>     MouseEvent
>
> IE Version 10.0.9200.16540
>     [object MSEventObj]
>
> Firefox Version 20.0.1
>     ReferenceError: event is not defined

I was bit by this "feature" of Chrome, Opera, and Safari because it worked as intended not as coded creating unexpected behavior in other browsers. While IE also has a global `event` variable, unlike the aforementioned browsers it does not assign that variable to the event that is currently firing. Firefox does not have a global `event` variable and therefore fails as soon as `event` is referenced.

Typically I use `e` for representing event variables which as expected fails the same way in all browsers. Why do Chrome, Opera and Safari have a global `event` variable which they assign this way? Is this behavior documented somewhere? Aside from don't use `event` for variable naming any advice for dealing with this "feature"?

Comment: Your function does not take `event` as a parameter, so `event` should not be defined in the function context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is event a global variable that is accessible everywhere inside the callback chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426497/is-event-a-global-variable-that-is-accessible-everywhere-inside-the-callback-cha)

Comment: @nullability That's the point of his question: he didn't expect it to be defined, but it is in most browsers. See the question I just linked to for the explanation.

Comment: There's a long history of information about browser differences with respect to the `event` object. If you're using jQuery, you should just define it as a function parameter in your handler.

Comment: @nullability did you read the question? I agree it was a programming mistake that I didn't catch because I hadn't **fully** tested cross browser. It was surprising behavior from Chrome, Opera and Safari. I would have expected a similar from them as I received from Firefox and IE. (Yes you understood that previous sentence to my mind IE did this correctly and Chrome etc. appear to be handling this wrong).

Comment: @barmar I love when I fail at searching SO for previously asked questions, though my hope is that my question comes across more as why is it designed this way than why does it function this way.

Comment: Why would you expect similar behavior between browsers? The entire history of web development is people fighting with browser incompatibilities.

Comment: `window.event` is an IE thing.  Check this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html#link3

Comment: @squint sadly, so true.

Comment: It started off as an IE thing. Some of IE's deviations have been adopted by other browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE has always provided a global `event` variable, unlike what the W3C standards dictate. The other browsers are doing the same in order to provide backward-compatibility with websites developed with old IE versions in mind.

> While IE also has a global event variable, unlike the aforementioned browsers it does not assign that variable to the event that is currently firing.

I believe it does.

Comment: At least IE10 doesn't, though I haven't tested behavior in IE9 or earlier.

Comment: Hm, then IE is following the standard when not in compatibility mode; unlike Chrome...