# JavaScript for handling Tab Key press

Tags: javascript

As we know, when we click on <kbd>TAB</kbd> key on keyboard, it allows us to navigate through all active href links present open webpage. Is it possible to read those urls by means of JavaScript?

example:

```
function checkTabPress(key_val) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        // Here read the active selected link.
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `document.activeElement` to get the currently focused element (if any, or the `body`). You can check that `.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "a"` and then read its `.href` property

Comment: Take a look at this question (didn't test it).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery

Comment: @Ian Did you mean `.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Well crap, of course I did. Haha thanks, didn't even realize that. With whatever method, I definitely meant to match the case obviously

Comment: Javascript Example to Handle TAB and TAB+SHIFT in a specified element to Loop in http://www.freakyjolly.com/navigate-form-field-link-elements-using-tab-and-shifttab-keys-in-webpage/

Answer (score 19):

You should be able to do this with the keyup event. To be specific, `event.target` should point at the selected element and `event.target.href` will give you the href-value of that element. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) for more information.

The following code is jQuery, but apart from the boilerplate code, the rest is the same in pure javascript. This is a `keyup` handler that is bound to every link tag.

```
$('a').on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
    if( e.which == 9 ) {
        console.log( e.target.href );
    }
} );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4PqUF/

Comment: This will point to the selected element at the time the tab key is pressed, not the new element that has been focused.

Comment: keydown will be fired before whatever the key does (and you can cancel whatever it does then), as far as I am aware (and as far as I can test in IE8) keyup will point to the new element, as the keyup is fired after whatever that key would do.

Comment: I didn't know that you could bind to the `a` element and still have it trigger if the previously focused element wasn't an `a`. +1, despite the use of jQuery.

Answer (score 14):

Having following html:

```
<!-- note that not all browsers focus on links when Tab is pressed -->
<a href="http://example.com">Link</a>

<input type="text" placeholder="Some input" />
<a href="http://example.com">Another Link</a>

<textarea>...</textarea>
```

You can get to active link with:

```
// event listener for keyup
function checkTabPress(e) {
    "use strict";
    // pick passed event or global event object if passed one is empty
    e = e || event;
    var activeElement;
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        // Here read the active selected link.
        activeElement = document.activeElement;
        // If HTML element is an anchor <a>
        if (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
            // get it's hyperlink
            alert(activeElement.href);
    }
}

var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener('keyup', checkTabPress);
```

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kolkabes/esMQD/7/).

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I'm pretty sure it does. Try [full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/kolkabes/esMQD/embedded/result/) and press Tab a couple of times. Shift-Tab works too.

Comment: Take my words back. I doesn't but not in every browser. Let me come up with a cross-browser code.

Comment: Whatever browser it works in, that browser has serious issues with its JavaScript engine...

Comment: I don't think Chrome has any serious issues =)

Comment: I guess yours will work in Chrome, Safari, IE 10 in compatibility mode, and older versions of IE.

Answer (score 4):

Only one suggestion instead of `9` you can use `KeyCodes`.`TAB`.

Comment: Or `e.key === 'Tab'`

Answer (score 1):

Given this piece of HTML code:

```
<a href='https://facebook.com/'>Facebook</a>
<a href='https://google.ca/'>Google</a>
<input type='text' placeholder='an input box'>
```

We can use this JavaScript:

```
function checkTabPress(e) {
    'use strict';
    var ele = document.activeElement;

    if (e.keyCode === 9 && ele.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        console.log(ele.href);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    checkTabPress(e);
}, false);
```

I have bound an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) element for the `keyUp` event, which triggers a function to check if the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key was pressed (or technically, released).

The function checks the [currently focused element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) and whether the [`NodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName) is `a`. If so, it enters the `if` block and, in my case, writes the value of the `href` property to the JavaScript console.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrjD2/)

Comment: IE 9, Firefox, and Chrome all work for mine and all of my variables are defined.

Comment: Why do you wrap callback function into another useless callback?

Comment: Because I'm passing a parameter.

Comment: That parameter is an event and it gets passed anyway.

Comment: "it gets passed anyway" Maybe that's why your solution isn't cross-browser compatible, see my comment on your answer and also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306486/unexpected-access-to-event-variable-across-browsers).

Comment: If it doesn't get passed it's likely that there is a global variable 'event' so you can just choose between them.

Comment: Thanks, for the sample. I also used key code 9 in my program, but it didn't work now in safari and chrome...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <body>
   <div class="linkCollection">
             <a tabindex=1 href="www.demo1.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=2 href="www.demo2.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=3 href="www.demo3.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=4 href="www.demo4.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=5 href="www.demo5.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=6 href="www.demo6.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=7 href="www.demo7.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=8 href="www.demo8.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=9 href="www.demo9.com">link</a>    
             <a tabindex=10 href="www.demo10.com">link</a>   
        </div>

</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".linkCollection a").focus(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    console.log(href);
    // href variable holds the active selected link.
  });
});
</script>
```

don't forgot to add jQuery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: using a tabindex larger then 0 disrupts the tab order and it  isn't recommended.

Comment: Question, If I have a separate javascript file, do I add the jQuery library on the HTML or in the separate JavaScript file?

Comment: Fine with separate JavaScript file as well. we just need jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Use `event.key` instead.

Here are the values you can use to assert against `event.key`:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values

Use this JavaScript solution:

```js
  function keyPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Tab") {
       // ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **TAB & TAB+SHIFT** in a **Specified container or element**

**[Source](http://www.freakyjolly.com/navigate-form-field-link-elements-using-tab-and-shifttab-keys-in-webpage/)**

we will handle **TAB & TAB+SHIFT key listeners** first

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            lastIndex = 0;
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9) var thisTab = $(":focus").attr("tabindex");
                if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    if (e.shiftKey) {
                        //Focus previous input
                        if (thisTab == startIndex) {
                            $("." + tabLimitInID).find('[tabindex=' + lastIndex + ']').focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (thisTab == lastIndex) {
                            $("." + tabLimitInID).find('[tabindex=' + startIndex + ']').focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            var setTabindexLimit = function(x, fancyID) {
                console.log(x);
                startIndex = 1;
                lastIndex = x;
                tabLimitInID = fancyID;
                $("." + tabLimitInID).find('[tabindex=' + startIndex + ']').focus();
            }
            /*Taking last tabindex=10 */
            setTabindexLimit(10, "limitTablJolly");
        });
```

In **HTML** define **tabindex**

```
        <div class="limitTablJolly">
            <a tabindex=1>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=2>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=3>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=4>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=5>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=6>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=7>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=8>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=9>link</a>    
             <a tabindex=10>link</a>   
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the keydown event. To be specific, event.target should point at the selected element and event.target.href will give you the href-value of that element. See mdn for more information.

The following code is jQuery, but apart from the boilerplate code, the rest is the same in pure javascript. This is a keydown handler that is bound to every link tag.

```
$('a').on( 'keydown ', function( e ) {
if( e.which == 9 ) {
    console.log( e.target.href );
}});
```

Answer (score -10):

You need to use Regular Expression
For Website URL it is

> var urlPattern =
>   /(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/

Use this Expression as in example

> var regex = new RegExp(urlPattern );  var t = 'www.google.com';
>   var res = t.match(regex /g);

For You have to pass your web page as string to this javascript in variable t and get array

Comment: This not enough to answer the question.