# get title of items selected using TAB button, on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, joomla3.0

I have a web application with no images in it. It is for visually impaired people. It is navigated using TAB button. How can I get the title/text of the selected web page like button,menu,etc. By selected I mean using TAB button, not mouse click. Using Javascript or any other language.

Comment: you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316395/javascript-for-handling-tab-key-press it almost answers you question

Comment: I want a 'TAB-over' effect, similar to 'mouse-over' effect or hover effect in CSS. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.focusin()`](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) method of jQuery library. Try to navigate on the form inputs from the snippet below using <kbd>TAB</kbd> button.

```js
$(document).focusin(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="input1"/>
  <input type="text" name="input2"/>
  <input type="text" name="input3"/>
</form>
```

I used name property of the event target in my example, but you could get any property value. For example

```
$(document).focusin(function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target).attr("type"));
});
```

It is possible to get `id` and another info by same way.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot.