# Detect when the Tab-Key is pressed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, keypress

I would like to detect when the user clicks the tab key on their keyboard, using Javascript.

I've tried this:

```
document.onkeypress = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}
```

And there it logges keys like letters, numbers and charcters, but not tab, ecs, backspace, enter or other keys like those.

Is there any way of doing so?

*Edit: btw, I can only use pure Javascript for this project, no libraries like jQuery etc.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316821/6999390

Comment: @DanCantir I'm sorry, but I can't use jQuery or any other library for this project.

Comment: `keypress` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The comment on your question, gives you jQuery solution that will not work.

You need to do it this way with vanilla JS. `keyCode` is property on event object, that stores the pressed keyboard button.

Here, you have all keycodes that you can use
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

```js
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 9) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I type this into my code editor, it puts a line over the text,and says that 'keyCode' is deprecated. And it logged nothing out when I tryed.

Comment: One more thing: tab is handled using `keydown`, not `keypress`.

Comment: @TobiasH. that's correct. Instead of `e.keyCode`, you can use `e.key`, which takes a string instead of a numerical code (in this case, `"Tab"`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
})
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 1):

You can use keydown instead.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  document.body.textContent = e.keyCode;
  if(e.keyCode === 9){
     document.body.textContent += ' Tab pressed';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a couple of things from the different answers on my post, and I got it to work.

```
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Tab') {
        console.log(e.key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabkey is an event code. You can catch that event and use `e.keyCode ===9` to get the Tab. I think it will still go to the next element in the tabIndex so you will need to preventDefault as well.