# After every alert page refreshes it should not refresh to stop refresh i used prevent default working fine in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Event . prevent default work in chrome but not working in firefox i have tried both methods but is not  working i have searched for all the possible solutions but it didn't work.
If you want me to post all of my code i'll post it if you didn't found error.

```
function validate_calc(e){
    event.preventDefault();



function validate_calc(event){
event.preventDefault();

if ($('input[name=water]:checked').length > 0) {

    var $radio = $('input[name=water]:checked');
    var id = $radio.attr('id');
    if(id == 'water'){
    if($('input[name=rad_waters]:checked').length > 0){
        if($('input[name=water_types]:checked').length > 0){
            $value = jQuery.trim($(".cal_input").val());
            if($value == ""){
            alert('Please Insert Values');
            return;
            } else {
                if($.isNumeric($(".cal_input").val())){
                var form_data = {
                 length: $('input[name="length"]').val(),
                 width: $('input[name="width"]').val(),
                    };

                    jQuery.ajax({
                    type        : "POST",
                    data        : form_data,
                    url         : baseurl+'solar_calculator/calculate_area',
                    success     : function(msg){
                    alert(msg);return;  
                    }
                    });
                }else{
                    alert('Value should be in Numbers.');
                    return;
                   }
            }
        }else{
            alert('Select a Sub water type');
            return;
        }
        }else{
        alert('Select a water type.');
        return;
        }
    } else {
    $value = jQuery.trim($(".cal_input").val());
            if($value == ""){
            alert('Please Insert Values');
            return;
            } else {
                if($.isNumeric($(".cal_input").val())){
                    var form_data = {
                 length: $('input[name="length"]').val(),
                 width: $('input[name="width"]').val(),
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({
                    type        : "POST",
                    data        : form_data,
                    url         : baseurl+'solar_calculator/calculate_area',
                    success     : function(msg){
                    alert(msg);return;  
                    }
                    });
                }else{
                    alert('Value should be in Numbers.');
                    return;
                   }
            }
    }
    } else {
alert('Please Select a water type');
return;
}
}
```

or i use this method it even didn't work

```
function validate_calc(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event - event prevent default don't work on function.

do it with id 
as

```
$('#myid').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault;
alert('am i working....'); return
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the event as "e" parameter in the function and then reference it with "event"? The correct syntax should be

```
function validate_calc(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

Also in order your code to work you MUST pass correct event value to the function, otherwise it won't work.

The reason your code works in chrome but not in firefox is that you are using super global variable "event" which is defined in chrome but not in firefox. You can read more here [Unexpected access to "event" variable across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306486/unexpected-access-to-event-variable-across-browsers)

Exmaple code that will work:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    validate_calc(e);
}
```

Example code that will NOT work:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    validate_calc();
}
```

Comment: i have tried it with both methods with function validate_calc(e){e.preventDefault(); not working??

Comment: What are you passing for "e" value? It should be the triggered event. Please provide js fiddle example.

Comment: Shaddy i have posted all my js script now you can see what the problem is i can't fiddle it its dynamically written in php.

Comment: Well then paste the code where you are calling this function, because the function itself is correct, the value passed to the function must be wrong. What is the output when you use console.log(e) at the start of the function?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if some value which is passed to function is wrong it shouldn't work in chrome too but its working fine in chrome.

Comment: No it is not working correct across all browsers because you are using "event" varible which in different browsers is like supoer global and is defined (in chrome for example) but in other browsers like firefox it is undefined. You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306486/unexpected-access-to-event-variable-across-browsers

So in order your code to work you must pass correct event value to the function.