# JavaScript stopImmediatePropagation not working in event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to use *stopImmediatePropagation* to prevent a second (mousedown) hadler on the same element to fire, but it doesn't work. Code sample:

```js
$(function() {
  var showEventsMessage = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      eventType: 'CLICK',
      eventTarget: this,
      suffix: '<br>'
    }, options);
    var message = options.eventType + ': ' +
      (options.eventTarget.nodeName || 'unknown') +
      options.suffix;
    $('#Messages').append(message);
  }

  $('.clickable').click(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
  }).dblclick(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
  }).mousedown(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }).mousedown(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type,
      suffix: '#2<br>'
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clickable'>CLICK HERE ...
  <p class='clickable'>or here!</p>
</div>
<div id="Messages"></div>
```

However, if I add an *event* argument to the event handler that calls *stopImmediatePropagation* (in code see line with "ARGUMENT ADDED HERE"), it does work! Since *event* is a global object, how is this possible, I don't understand what effectively changes...!? Code example:

```js
$(function() {
  var showEventsMessage = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      eventType: 'CLICK',
      eventTarget: this,
      suffix: '<br>'
    }, options);
    var message = options.eventType + ': ' +
      (options.eventTarget.nodeName || 'unknown') +
      options.suffix;
    $('#Messages').append(message);
  }

  $('.clickable').click(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
  }).dblclick(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
  }).mousedown(function(event) /* ARGUMENT ADDED HERE */ {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }).mousedown(function() {
    showEventsMessage.call(this, {
      eventType: event.type,
      suffix: '#2<br>'
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clickable'>CLICK HERE ...
  <p class='clickable'>or here!</p>
</div>
<div id="Messages"></div>
```

Comment: [Firefox doesn't define window.event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426497/is-event-a-global-variable-that-is-accessible-everywhere-inside-the-callback-cha#comment36646426_6426581). What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, Opera, Edge and IE all define window.event while event listener is executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the parameter is a jQuery event object and without the parameter it uses the original JS event object. You get the jQuery version because you initialize the event handler with jQuery.

The function that you're trying to call "stopImmediatePropagation" is a jQuery function and is not defined in the original JS event, and that is why it won't work.

Comment: **^ This is not true!** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Answer (score -1):

Notice that you have added **jQuery event handlers** in both cases.

In first case, you are trying to stop a jQuery handler from being executed by calling `stopImmediatePropagation` on a global (native JS) event. Hence, it does not work.

When you extract `event` from arguments, you are calling `stopImmediatePropagation` on `jQuery.Event`. Hence, it is successful in stopping execution of jQuery handler.

Comment: Sorry but this just a rephrase of @Joost_96 answer. And since he posted it first, he deserves the credit for the same

Comment: Fair enough @TarunLalwani. When I opened this question, no answer was there so I posted this answer.

Comment: Happens sometimes, you should make sure to refresh the page before posting an answer. That helps avoid such situations

Comment: Sure. Will take care next time.

Answer (score -1):

Actully `stopImmediatePropagation` is a jquery method. 
By passing `event` in `mousedown` event callback it pass jquery reference and `stopImmediatePropagation` is then called with it and works, But when you do not pass `event` param, it points to the default javascript event object, which do not have reference of `stopImmediatePropagation`. So, it doen't work there
See: [Inside the Event Handling Function](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/)