# What is the difference between event function Object with parameter and without parameter

Tags: javascript

What is the difference if I pass the parameter to the function of the event or not, because if I do not put it, it will do the same job if I put the parameter
Examples

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let p = document.getElementById("p");

function draw(x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = 'x';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = y + 'px';
    div.style.left = x + 'px';
    document.body.append(div);
}

document.body.onclick = funcation(event){
    draw(event.clientX, event.clientY)
}

document.body.onclick = function () {
    console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY)
}
```

Comment: [Is event a global variable that is accessible everywhere inside the callback chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6426497) | [Why is 'event' available globally in Chrome but not FF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30159017) | [Get calling Event inside of Class-Function without Parameter in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68854376)

Comment: thank you, Can I ask something, how can you give me same Qusstion ?